# How do I import all functions in a file/name space?

Tags: php, namespaces, alias, php-7.1

I have a file

```
<?php namespace a1;
function a(){}
function b(){}
function c(){}
```

In another file, I would like to import all the functions from the first file as if they ware in the same namespace. Right now, I have to do something like this:

```
<php
include 'file1.php';
use a1\{a,b,c};
```

I want this to be more dynamic as I keep adding functions to file 1 which is part of my bootstrap files.

Comment: There are some points that you have to keep in mind. `namespaces` should always used with an `autoloader`, you better define one class with static mehtods instead of single functions. Then you can extend the class with new method, but the `use` is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Better do it in this way:

```
<?php namespace a1;
class func {
   static function a(){}
   static function b(){}
   static function c(){}
}
```

and

```
<?php
include 'file1.php';#better register an autoloader
use a1\func as f;
f::a();
```

So know you can add more and more mehtod, but there is no need for any update of `use`.
And you can just wrap `class func {}` around your functions and add to all `static` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the parent namespace:

```
namespace a1 {
    function a(){echo 'yello!';}
    function b(){}
    function c(){}
}

namespace a2 {
    use a1;

    echo a1\a();
}
```

### Output :

`yello!`

---

for you example :

```
<php
include 'file1.php';
use a1;

// call any function under the namespace a1;

var_dump(a1\a());
```